# Adobe Media Server Video Recording

Tags: adobe, adobe-media-server

As comparison page http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-professional/buying-guide-comparison.html points Video recording is not included in standard edition of AMS. What is "Video recording"? Is there any white paper describing what that means. Will incoming streams be saved in some folder in flv format?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [this whitepaper](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/ams/pdfs/ams5-intro-wp.pdf) the only reference to "recording" is for "Multicast ingest and recording" using RTMFP.

If you just want to publish a stream to a server using RTMP and save that, I'm pretty sure the Standard edition can do that. Using this method, incoming streams can be saved in a folder in flv format.